# What is the best view to sculpt in? Is it in the persective or orthographic view

Tags: sculpting, orthographic

I tried sculpting a human head and according to the tutorials I watched, they normally sculpt in orthographic view and so I did so and in orthographic mode, my head models actually look good but once I switch to perspective mode then the model looks terrible, nothing is in the right proportion. I also tried exporting it to Unity in order to find out if it's only in Blender and in unity my model still looks weird.

I then tried to model in perspective mode and in that mode its extremely hard to sculpt so I want to know which mode is the right one to sculpt in so that I can continue sculpting.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't necessarily a "correct" view to do anything in in blender.

However, know that in almost all cases, perspective view will be the view you will be viewing your model in afterwards, and is the physically correct way that people view the world.

Orthographic mode is really useful, especially if you want to be able to compare distances and look at a model directly from the side, but I don't usually need to do that in sculpting, so I would recommend perspective view.

If you could elaborate a little more on what you mean by "extremely hard to sculpt", I might be able to provide better advice.

Comment: By "extremely hard to sculpt" I meant that the view or objects shape kept on changing. For example when I move closer to my head model in perspective view, the head has an awkward peak on the top but when I move away by scrolling then that awkward peak is gone on the head

Comment: Not to mention that from a far range the nose looks normal in perspective mode but when I get closer it looks huge and irregular. So you see sculpting a human head would be near impossible because the view and size of the head keeps changing all the time leaving me unsure of what the actual head looks like. @person132

Comment: @Divine What you're describing is totally normal. If you look at yourself in a mirror and move slowly closer to it, you'll see similar effects; it's just amplified in Blender because of how close/far you can get and how quickly you can move between distances. The model isn't changing as you move around; what's changing is the way it's foreshortened by distance - which happens in real life. That "awkward peak" is probably just a small bump that is very obvious when close to it and harder to see from a distance. If the perspective effect is distorting things too much, try zooming out a little.

Comment: If field of view in perspective mode is too intense, you can increase the focal length of the viewport camera in the N panel > View > Focal length. The higher you go, the closer you get to an orthographic look.

Answer (score 1):

Organic modelling and sculpting can be a tricky method to get used to.

I myself am definitely no expert but there a few things that I learnt from tutorials, blogs and answers which helped me figure out how to go about it.

As Person132 says there is no "correct" way of doing it but using both views in conjuncture is probably the best practice. I'll provide a few images of a spider I sculpted a while ago (sorry for the gross images, it's my best example) but it shows how I would use the top down and bottom orthographic view to get a rough scale of the object and then use perspective view to sculpt the finer details, using reference images dotted around my scene.

[image: orthographic view]

[image: Perspective view]

[image: Close up view]

You should always keep the camera moving as you sculpt to help you get the proper proportions all around, so if you're sculpting the nose in your example, start from the side view in orthographic view to get a reference of the size/length. Then switch to front view and adjust your width and then move into perspective and start tweaking it always referring back to a reference image, looking at if the apex is sharp on rounded, how high the bridge goes up in relation to the eyes, if the Ala is a big or small etc... (anatomy names from https://teachmeanatomy.info/head/organs/the-nose/external-nose/).

I can't model anything properly without a reference image in my scene, or just a bunch of reference images with different angles using Kuadro reference tool, otherwise it just looks un-proportional and weird.

Hope this helps someone one day.